How to know the property type from a place returned from Google Autocomplete API
Background: I run a small e-commerce website. One of our features is using the Google Autocomplete API to help customers simplify the address input process and increase address accuracy. This feature has worked very well for a long time.
New Requirement: I now need to determine the property type of the addresses that customers input. Specifically, I need to know if an address is residential, commercial, or belongs to limited areas like schools, farms, hotels, etc.
Question: Do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Types available for an address or place are listed on this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

@Kat, thank you for the help. I've read this article and if I was right, I think this type (Table 1) was designed to restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a certain type by passing the type parameter, which is not present in the result response from the API.
